# Spring Boot can no longer bind configuration properties when migrating to version 3+ in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, configuration, configurationproperties

After migrating an app to Spring Boot 3.0.1 the configuration properties can no longer be loaded from the `application.yml` file.

It does not work on any class that previously was ok.
The following configuration spec started failing with uninitialized property for `region`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws")
class AwsConfig {
    lateinit var region: Region
    var endpointUrl: URI? = null
}
```

I researched more modern ways of instantiating the properties and came up with the following:

```
package ...

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ConstructorBinding
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws")
data class AwsConfig @ConstructorBinding constructor(
    val region: Region
)
```

The entry point is annotated with the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class Application
```

That causes NPEs now, leading me to believe this is rather a read-level issue. Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Roots of the stacktrace:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6fa1dc0c testClass = com.pkg.ApplicationContextTest, ...]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventConsumerLauncher' defined in file ... Error creating bean with name 'aws-com.pkg.AwsConfig': Could not bind properties to 'AwsConfig' : prefix=aws, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'aws-com.pkg.AwsConfig': Could not bind properties to 'AwsConfig' : prefix=aws, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true
    at app//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBound.from(ConstructorBound.java:46)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'aws' to com.pkg.AwsConfig
    at app//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.handleBindError(Binder.java:387)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.pkg.AwsConfig]: Constructor threw exception
    at app//org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:223)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.pkg.AwsConfig.<init>, parameter region
    at com.pkg.AwsConfig.<init>(AwsConfig.kt)
```

The faulty `application.yml` file looks like this:

```yaml
server:
  port: -1

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: integration

app:
  #...

aws:
  region: ${AWS_REGION:eu-west-1}
```

Comment: please share the stacktrace of the error to understand what is happening

Comment: @Panagiotis Bougioukos done that, please check if you're still interested

Comment: share the properties from application.yaml and the configurationProperties classes as they exist in your code. It seems that you may have some error there

Comment: @Panagiotis Bougioukos added the `application.yml` that is used when the error occurs. I guess the ENV interpolation looks risky.

Answer (score 1):

High chances you are affected by this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33710), which is still open for `spring-boot 3.0.1`.

You either apply the workarounds discussed under this issue, or wait for solution which probably be rolled out in `spring-boot 3.0.2`.

Answer (score 1):

This was an enterprise project where we explicitly declared some dependencies inline so that we could mitigate CVEs through version patching.

It turned out that for some reason, removing `io.netty` & `org.apache.tomcat.embed` declarations (used in the `implementation` scope) resolved the above problem.